# flex mobile : textInput does not clear prompt on focus

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6, flex-mobile

a simple

```
<s:TextInput x="163" y="117"  prompt="hello"/>
```

Does not clear the prompt on focus, but clears the prompt when user first type in a letter.

**This is the behaviour on flex mobile** (behaviour is OK on swf )

Is that a bug and how to correct that ?

regards

Comment: I assume since you tagged this as Flex 4.6; you are using Flex 4.6?  And I assume from your code, you are using the default skin class for the mobile TextInput?  Perhaps StageText--used on mobile--operates differently than a Flash TextField?

Answer (score 2):

There May be an-other way to get rid of that, but my approach is that you may add a focusIn event and do some thing like :

```
<s:TextInput id="textInput" x="10" y="24" prompt="Enter SomeThing" focusIn="textinput1_focusInHandler(event)"/>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function textinput1_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textInput.prompt = "";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

may that should work for you...

Answer (score 1):

www.Flextras.com is on the right path. I had the same issues with TextInput on iPad where the field wouldn't display as a password when I needed it to.

All you need to do is manually apply the mobile TextInput skin.

```
<s:TextInput x="163" y="117" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" prompt="hello"/>
```

You can see the answer provided to me in a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419068/ios-textinput-displayaspassword-doesnt-displayaspassword).

Comment: This, in essence, uses the Flex 4.5 mobile skin class for TextInput.  [which predates StageText, therefore does not use it].

Comment: @www.Flextras.com After some quick Googling, it appears you're right. Regardless, it fixed all the issues I was having. You lose the benefits of StageText, but in my experience, the disadvantages (especially that StageText rests above everything else and is a pain when scrolling) far outweigh those benefits

Comment: Yep; I was only offering clarification.  It is not necessarily a bad thing.  There are trade-offs either way.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Fair enough. Thanks for that clarification. I was unaware that is what that skin class was/did until you mentioned it. Hopefully they don't remove it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution to hide prompt on focus is pretty easy, just add a style declaration like this

```
s|TextInput{
    showPromptWhenFocused: false;
}
```

or in a class

```
.noPromptOnFocus{
    showPromptWhenFocused: false;
}
```

If you use the second approach, your TextInput should look something like

```
<s:TextInput id="myTextInput" prompt="Write something here.." styleName="noPromptWhenFocused" />
```

This works fine no matter if you're using StageText or the TextInputSkin.