# flex mobile: cropped delete icon on ipado on textInput component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

here is my CSS for textInput

```
s|TextInput{
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin");
    contentBackgroundColor:#FFFFFF;
    focusAlpha:0;
    showPromptWhenFocused:false;
}
```

and I use simple:

```
    <s:TextInput id="id1" />
    <s:TextInput id="id1" height="40" />
    <s:TextInput id="id1" height="60 />
```

On iphone/ipad: the close icon appears top cropped: 
[image]

Any idea how to fix that ? (or even how to remove that X icon) ?

Answer (score 1):

The icon is a set height and, at least in Flex, doesn't adjust its size. The cropping is from the height of the textfield (read: *not* the TextInput component, but the actual field the text goes in). Because that field is not as tall as the icon, the icon gets cropped.

There are two solutions:

1. The obvious one is to increase the height on the TextInput field until that icon is no longer cropped. You could just take your screenshot and measure out the pixels being cropped, if you want.
2. You get that icon because TextInput uses StageText. StageText uses native text rendering as opposed to Flash text rendering. In ideal situations, StageText is perfect. However, the situation is rarely ideal. To get around this, you simply apply the mobile TextInput skin `skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"` to your TextInput component(s). As [www.Flextras.com pointed out to me yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048099/flex-mobile-textinput-does-not-clear-prompt-on-focus/13053170#13053170), this reverts the TextInput back to its behavior prior to Flex 4.6, which introduced StageText.

Either one of those solutions should work for you. You just need to choose which is best. I prefer Option #2 because, as I mentioned, there are other issues with StageText (such as getting displayAsPassword to function correctly) that switching to that skin fixes

Comment: Based on the code he posted in the question; he is using the spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin class; set via CSS.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com ...you're right. I am blind. I only checked the component itself. To the asker: my apologies. I would still attempt my first solution, even if my second solution is already being used (and obviously not entirely correct if you are still getting the icon)

Comment: I tried with various height and still have the same problem !
    <s:TextInput id="id1" />
    <s:TextInput id="id1" height="40" />
    <s:TextInput id="id1" height="60 />
I tried with : default height, 40 pixels and 60 pixles and all these have this problem !

Comment: Try increasing the font size. The height of the actual input field may depend on the text height, not the component height.

Answer (score 0):

I would try editing the skin, because that is where the icon crop is happening